# where did the 5th element of the array go after adding the 'a' and 'y' characters, and why isn't the character assigned instead of the nul terminator?

Tags: c++

After adding characters, the array must contain 6 characters "roaday" but the for loop is executed 7 times and when `if (p [i] == '\ 0') {p [i] = 'b';}` the character b will not be assigned instead of the nul terminator .

how can I assign a character instead of a nul terminator  and why instead of 6 characters there are 7 characters???

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char x[100];

    cin >>x; // cin >> "road"

    char* p;
    p = x;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (p[i] == '\0')
        {
/*
no character is assigned to nul terminator 
*/
 /* this line */    p[i] = p[0];
          p[i++] = 'a';
          p[i++] = 'y';
          p[i++] = '\0';

          cout << endl << p << endl;
          break;
        }
    }

    cout << p;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure? This looks like the loop will execute five times to me - until it finds the first nul terminator - and print "roadray" twice. The extra 'r' in the middle comes from `p[i++] = p[0];` - what did you mean by that?

Comment: 1) "_when if (p [i] == '\ 0') {p [i] = 'b';} the character b will not be assigned instead of the nul terminator ._" Please provide [mre] that produces said behavior. 2) "_why instead of 6 characters there are 7 characters_" Your array always contain `100` characters, due to it being declared as `char x[100];`

Comment: As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, please extract and provide a [mcve] and pay attention to consistent formatting. After all, you want people to read it.

Comment: `/* this line */    p[i] = p[0];` OK, this now replaces the nul terminator with the first character from the string 'r', but no longer increments 'i'. So the next line, `p[i++] = 'a';` will overwrite the 'r' with an 'a'.

Comment: "no character is assigned to nul terminator" - yes it is? Both of the next two lines overwrite the original nul terminator at p[i]. If you think that the line you've marked isn't setting a character then it is, but you're overwriting that character with the next one. If you wanted to keep this extra 'r' then change `p[i]` back to `p[i++]` so that i is incremented after you've set the 'r'.

Comment: And as I should have suggested in the first place: please step through this code in a debugger if you haven't already, and watch what happens to p and i at each step.

Comment: @Rup    if (road + ay) then it means | r | o | a | d | \ 0 | a | y | \ 0 | ?

Comment: Generally no, if you're using C functions to concatenate strings then you'd get  | r | o | a | d | a | y | \ 0 | . And the way you're doing it here will get that too. If you left the \0 in the middle then the cout would just print "road"

Answer (score 1):

> when if (p [i] == '\ 0') {p [i] = 'b';} the character b will not be assigned instead of the nul terminator

This alone would work but in your code you are overwriting this assignment with the next line because you are probably misunderstanding the function of `i++`

You are entering the if-statement when `i==4` which leads to:

```
p[4] = p[0] // overwrite '\0' with 'r'
p[4] = 'a'; // i is increased afterwards so you overwrite 'r' again
p[5] = 'y';
p[6] = '\0';
// i equals 7 now
```

So for overwriting the `'\0'` with the first character and then append `'a'` and `'y'` you could just change `p[i] = p[0]` to `p[i++] = p[0]` to not replace this position twice.

Comment: but  it iant  working  output  is roaday     but  not roadRay

Comment: @user12918858 Did u adopt the change properly? Checkout the [adjusted code](https://onlinegdb.com/SyVv4DtQU) - It outputs `roadray`